# Having issues joining on items within a struct in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have these two datasets that I'm looking to join

`df`

```
 |-- key: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- subId: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- x: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- y: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- level: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- otherItems: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- nameRestaurant: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- thing: struct (nullable = true)
```

and another `df2`

```
 |-- key: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- subId: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- x: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- y: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- level: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- attribute: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- address: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- someThing: struct (nullable = true)
```

I need to join the two datasets on the `key` column, i.e.

`val df3 = df.join(df2, Seq("key"), "left")`

however doing that join results in no matches while I'm sure they exist

When I try to expand the join by doing

```
val df3 = df.join(df2, Seq("key.name", "key.subId.x", "key.subId.y", "key.subId.level"), "left")
```

I'm getting an error

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: USING column `key.name` cannot be resolved on the left side of the join.
```

Is it not possible to join on items underneath a struct?
Can someone advice the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In spark3.3.1 that was ok!
but in spark2.X versions you can use the below solution:

1. create a new column on each df which is cast of `key` to string and use the join operation on that field after join operation you can remove that field:

```py
df.withColumn("castOfKey" , col("key").cast("string") )\
  .join(
        df2.withColumn("castOfKey" , col("key").cast("string") ),
        Seq("castOfKey"),
        "left"
).drop("castOfKey")
```